# winapi c - read/write mbr of system drive

Tags: c, winapi, mbr

Does anyone have any example code that shows how to identify the system boot harddisk, and read/write the mbr from the harddisk in windows xp and vista?

I know createfile can be used. But I do not know how to properly identify which device is the boot device.

Like how do you find out which ones you are meant to use?   \.\Volume{GUID}\ or  \?\Device\HarddiskVolumeX etc?

Comment: Danger! Danger Will Robinson! - Why exactly are you needing to write to the MBR?

Comment: @Dav: There are lots of legitimate uses. But there are also lotsa ways to screw it all up.

Comment: We are using a custom boot loader, and I want to be able to update the text messages that it displays, its just a couple short strings in the MBR. I already know i can do it with dd etc. but I was wondering what the proper API way to do it so it works in vista with all the security.

Answer (score 0):

you could try looking through the source of rawwrite for windows http://www.chrysocome.net/rawwrite

Comment: Unfortuently there is some trick to it that was added for nt6, rawwrite doesnt work on vista or windows7.